# Can't seem to start up tomcat 8 under ecilpse on Win 7

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, java, eclipse, tomcat

Windows 7 Pro, eclipse, java EE environment. I downloaded the tomcat zip file, unzipped it into c:\program files\apache\tomcat-whatever. I can run eclipse from the command line, and entering "localhost:8080" into a browser address bar will give me the tomcat home page like it's supposed to.

In eclipse, I added this as a server. When I start it, a new "javaw.exe" process shows up in Task Manager and stays there, and eclipse says the server is running. But entering "localhost:8080" into the address bar on the browser says the resource is not available.

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the tomcat you are running might be conflicting with the one which eclipse is running.

Try telnet port 8080 on localhost.

Also you need to run the project to show in tomcat.

Comment: Just restarted the machine and ran it again, same result, so there's no conflict with another tomcat instance. I just noticed that, when I run it from eclipse, there are no log files. Removed read-only permissions from all folders below the tomcat installation folder, but get the same result (after reboot and restart). Oddly, the title in the tab on the browser says tomcat, as though it is the server saying "resource not available". Am trying to set up a test project now; used wizard to create one, need to search for what else it needs...